Water keeps draining into the toilet when the float valve shuts off
I have a three Kohler toilets all with a center overflow tubes (plastic PVC pipe).  One of them has constantly been leaking water into the bowl.  I replaced the fill valve and flapper, but water still leaks into the bowl slowly causing a huge waste of water.  When I take the fill tube out of the overflow tube the problem goes away and no longer leaks into the toilet.  I checked my other two toilets and realized that the metal clip holding the fill tube to the overflow tube no longer fills the bowl through that tube and instead the water goes directly into the tank.  Since putting the tube into the tank instead of the siphon tube seems to solve the problem on the one leaky toilet, and neither of the other toilets have the fill tube running into the overflow pipe I am wondering if just letting the flow tubes fill the tank instead of filling through the overflow pipe is okay.  If not, why not and what is the fix for the leaky toilet.

Did you clean around where the flapper valve sits?  Dirt/stuff on the valve seat will allow even a new valve to leak.

Thanks I will double check.  I did put in a new flapper valve and cleaned the port with my finger but will double check.

This sounds like textbook siphoning. You should not place the fill tube directly into the overflow tube because if the end of the tube ends up lower than the tank water level... tank water will siphon back through the valve. New fill valves come with a clip/bracket/holder to ensure that the fill tube sprays into the overflow tube without actually being inserted into it.
On most common toilets in the US, the water that enters the overflow tube is directed to the rim orifices in the bowl, and helps to wash the sides of the bowl with each flush. The amount of that flow can also affect the water level in the bowl, So... the drawbacks of leaving it the way you have it (fill tube spraying directly into the tank) is that you lose rim clean feature and potentially have lower water level in the bowl.

Put a couple drops of food coloring or a cup of black coffee into the tank. (not the bowl).
Leave the fill tube in the overflow.
Wait a few hours. if the water in the bowl shows the color of the food coloring or the coffee, the flapper or the flapper seat is not sealing correctly.
If the water in the bowl is still clear and the bowl is getting water, the fill valve is not adjusted correctly or not functioning properly and shutting off. Adjust it or replace it.

Very helpful.  Thanks.  I will give that a try.  I just replaced the fill valve, but will double check and see what happens.  Thanks for taking the time.  Will let you know

I spent a pile of money on flush valves/flappers and special ones for my particular models and finally discovered that the hose that goes into the overfill tube was in too far and that it was siphoning water out of the tank. The water would nicely fill the bowl and excess runs out the sewer pipe and used a lot of water uselessly.  Make sure that the hose end is above the tank high water level to avoid that siphoning action.  Simple fix.

Sounds like canonical leaking flush valve/"flapper".  If so, replacement parts for traditional US models, at least, are pretty well standardized and cheap. Water-saving models may be more complicated and require manufacturer specific parts.
